# Connecting to H2 Database in FTP Server (File Zilla) in java

Tags: java, database, ftp, h2

I am creating a java app to send messages which will auto Destruct.

So I want an online database in order to store the Username and Password of various users .
I am using H2 Database in order to store these details locally and Filezilla server as the local FTP Server.

So I want to know how I could use the same database after transferring it into the network.
This is the relevant part of my present Connection method :

```
    String current = new java.io.File( "." ).getCanonicalPath();
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(current,"/Files");
    System.out.println(path.toString());
    current+="/Files/Databases/Message";
    String host = "jdbc:h2:file:"+current;
    String uName = "sa";
    String uPass = "";
    con=new Connection[Size];
    stmt=new Statement[Size];
    for(int i=0;i<Size;i++)
    {
    con[i]=DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
    stmt[i]=con[i].createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    }
```

To be more specific , What should be the Host be after I move the DB to a remote FTP adress ?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understood the question. You want to know if you can use a database after you have moved it? The answer is yes. But how is this related with your code?

Comment: Not exactly . I want to know 'how' to use the database after I move it to an ftp location ( At present I am using FileZilla server and a local folder as the FTP folder ) .

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "how to use the database"?

Comment: What should my Host string be for an ftp address ?

Comment: The file needs to be on your hard disk. You can't open the database file on an FTP server; you first need to copy it to your hard disk.

Comment: Ok then , Thanks ... btw I don't know if I can use H2 in my program due to this problem . Anyway , H2 has been a great Database system which helped me a lot in my previous projects ...

Comment: OK, so you can't use H2. Well I don't think you can use _any_ database with this requirement.